# How to make a range of coordinates in pygame?

Tags: pygame

This is a pretty simple question, but I want to code something so that when you are in a certain range, and you click over something, it changes the background. Everything works fine so far, but I only know how to code it so that when you are the exact X and Y coordinates you're in range to click. How do I make it so that if you are in 100-300 X (for example) and 500 - 600 Y that you are in range, as oppose to the exact coordinates of 100 X, and 600 Y?

(here's the snippet of code I'm working with by the way, I can supply full code if you want.)

```
if 120+75 > mouse[0] > 120 and 50 + 125 > mouse[1] > 125 and x == 110 and y == 60:
    print('Click to change')
```

Comment: what is x and y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the top left position of the rectangular area (`x`, `y`) and the size of the area (`width`, `height`):

```py
x = 120
y = 125
width = 75
height = 50
```

The evaluate if the mouse is in the area:

```py
if x < mouse[0] x + width and y < mouse[1] y + height:
    print('Click to change')
```

I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and [`.collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint). Define a rectangle object by *(x, y, width, height)* and evaluate if the mouse poisition is in the rectangular area:

```py
rect = pygame.Rect(120, 125, 75, 50)
if rect.collidepoint(mouse):
    print('Click to change')
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your trying to make a button, in your code you have mouse and x and y, not sure what x and y are if mouse is mouse position, but here is how to do it with the button x position,y position, width and height.

```
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
if mouse_pos[0] > x_pos and mouse_pos[0] < x_pos + width:
    if mouse_pos[1] > y_pos and mouse_pos[1] < y_pos + height:
        if click:
            background = (255,255,255) #change background
```